# Changing Layout Issue Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, screen-orientation

I am an android app developer.I want to do the following in my app.

When I click on a button of my layout  it should change to landscape.If I will click on that button again it should changed to portrait.I know it is simple with

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

But there's a catch.

When after button clicked it is in landscape mode and I rotate the device It also detect device rotation and should changed to portrait view.

We know that after setting setRequestedOrientation onConfigurationChanged never called. So How can I do it.

I have added the following code:

```
toggleButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
     if (toggleButton.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("landscape")){
        landscapeMode(true);
        toggleButton.setText("portrait");
     } else {
        landscapeMode(false);
        toggleButton.setText("landscape");
    }
  }
});    


  public void toggleScreen(boolean fullscreen) {
    if (landscapeMode) {
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
         //After this it is not detecting device rotation but it is called when             I am clicking on the button first time.
    } else {
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR);
        //After this it is detecting device rotation but it is called when I am clicking on the button second time.
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because by default you have to set your activity as "Potrait" in manifest file. Like this.

```
 <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Now if you want to change mode of your phone using button click. You can use the following code snippet.

```
 button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(getRequestedOrientation() == ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
                setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
            } else {
                setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
            }
        }
    });
```

Also, you can save your data while your screen orientation changes.using

```
 @Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(final Bundle outState, PersistableBundle outPersistentState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState, outPersistentState);
  // Save UI state changes to the savedInstanceState.
  // This bundle will be passed to onCreate if the process is
  // killed and restarted.
  outState.putBoolean("landscape", true);
  // etc.
}
```

and get saved data in -

```
@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
  // Restore UI state from the savedInstanceState.
  // This bundle has also been passed to onCreate.
  boolean myBoolean = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("landscape");
}
```

Comment: First of all thanks a lot for your response.But it's not working